# when converting parameters to variables, connections are broken at dev time

Tags: azure-logic-apps

**How do I get up my connections to show up in the designer ?**

In my `logicapp.json` file I am setting the connection names to be functions of parameters like so:

```
  "variables": {
    "servicebus_1_Connection_Name": "[concat('servicebus-',parameters('logicAppName'))]",
    "azureblob_1_Connection_Name": "[concat('blob-',parameters('logicAppName'))]"
  },
```

However the designer doesn't like this:

[image]

When deploying, the connections show up no problem:

[image]

Comment: I might have missunderstod the question, why do you want them to be variables and not parameters?

Comment: i dont want the parameters to be modifiable externally thats why i made them variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click anywhere on the logic app, then press F4 to get the properties of the logic app:

[image]

Change the resource group to the appropriate one that has your connections!

[image]

After going through the above 2 requirements, your connections will be displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `parameters` instead of `variables` for this. Variables need to be instantiated while parameters only need to be declared, bear in mind that you will need to declare the parameter in both the logic app template and in the arm deployment template in the `logicapp.json` file and also in the `logicapp.parameters.json` file.

Comment: the whole point of making them variables is to have them be a function of the logic app name, which is parameterized, i dont want to make them parameters and allow external modification through a parameter file

Comment: the reason would be because there's no way to enforce some standard naming convention if you expose your parameters to be changed